# Trying to upload a CSV into Snowflake and the date column isn't recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The column contains dates in the following format:
dd/mm/yyyy

I've tried DATE, TIMESTAMP etc but whatever I do, I can't seem to upload the file.

Comment: You need to use conversion while loading, like copy into table_name from (select to_date($1,'dd/mm/yyyy'),$2,$3,... from @stage)

Comment: So I can't manually upload via the front end?

Comment: Are you referring to snowflake GUI = 'front end'?

Comment: When I select 'load table' and upload a csv file.

Comment: In case you are referring to snowflake GUI classic web console file upload functionality then it only offers limited functionality for data loading and ideally should not be used for loading complex or large data-sets. In any case you might try putting date format=dd/mm/yyyy in file_format - add/create a new file format (+ button in File Format ) in the load data wizard.

Comment: Upload it as varchar, then use an update statement to fix data type and format

Answer (score 1):

In the classic UI you can click on the `Load Table`button and follow the dialogs to upload your file. It is a bit hard to find. Click on `Databases` right to the big snowflake icon. Then select a database and a table. Then you should the the button. In the wizard there will be a step for defining the 'File Format'. There, you have to scroll down to define the date format. (see [Classic snowflake UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icQbt.png))

Without the classic UI you have to install SnowSQL on your device first (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html).
Start SnowSQL and apply the following steps:

1. Use the database where to upload the file to. You need various privileges for creating a stage, a fileformat, and a table. E.g. `USE TEST_DB`
2. Create the fileformat you want to use for uploading your csv file. E.g.

`CREATE FILE FORMAT "TEST_DB"."PUBLIC".MY_FILE_FORMAT TYPE = 'CSV' DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/mm/yyyy';`

3. Create a stage using this fileformat

`CREATE STAGE MY_STAGE file_format = "TEST_DB"."PUBLIC".MY_FILE_FORMAT;`

4. Now you can put your file to this stage

`PUT file://<file_path>/file.csv @MY_STAGE;`

5. You can check the upload with

`SELECT d.$1, ..., d.$N FROM @MY_STAGE/file.csv d;`

6. Then, create your table.
7. Copy the content from your stage to your table. If you want to transform your data at this point, you have to use an inner select. If not then the following command is enough.

`COPY INTO mycsvtable from @MY_STAGE/file.csv;`

You can find documentation for configuring the fileupload at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html
You can find documentation for configuring the stage at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html
You can find documentation for copying the staged file into a table https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

I recommend that you upload your file with disabled automatically date detection OR that your initial table has a string column instead of a date column. IMHO, it is easier to transform your upload afterwards using the `try_to_date` function. Using this function it is much easier to handle possible parsing errors.

e.g. `SELECT try_to_date(date_column, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as MY_DATE, IFNULL(MY_DATE, date_column) as MY_DATE_NOT_PARSABLE FROM upload;`

You see that it is pretty much to do for loading a simple CSV file to Snowflake. It becomes even more complicated when you take into account that every step can cause some specific failures and that your file might contain erroneous lines. This is why my team and I are working at Datameer to make these types of tasks easier. We aim for a simple drag and drop solution that does most of the work for you. We would be happy if you would try it out here: https://www.datameer.com/upload-csv-to-snowflake/